# How to use variables in gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: bash, variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use variables in my gitlab-ci.yml file. This variable is passed as a parameter to a batch file that'll either only build or build and deploy based on parameter passed in. I've tried many different ways to pass my variable into the batch file but each time the variable is treated more like a static string instead.

I've read gitlabs docs on variables but cant seem to make it work.

```
  - build  

variables:
  BUILD_PUBLISH_CONFIG_FALSE: 0
  BUILD_PUBLISH_CONFIG_TRUE: 1

# BUILD ===============================
build: &build
    stage: build  
    tags: 
      - webdev  
    script:       
      - ./build.bat %BUILD_CONFIG%

build:branch:
  <<: *build
  variables:
    BUILD_CONFIG: $BUILD_PUBLISH_CONFIG_FALSE
  only:
    - /^(feature|hotfix|release)\/.+$/

build:branch:
  <<: *build
  variables:
    BUILD_CONFIG: $BUILD_PUBLISH_CONFIG_TRUE
  only:
    - /^(stage)\/.+$/

build:branch:
  <<: *build
  variables:
    BUILD_CONFIG: $BUILD_PUBLISH_CONFIG_TRUE
  only:
    - /^(master)\/.+$/
```

When watching gitlab's ci script execute, I expect ./build.bat 0, or ./build.bat 1.
Each time it prints out as ./build.bat %BUILD_CONFIG%

Comment: It seems the issue is withing the variables on the lower portion of the code. Using variables stirctly from the top works. I can't seem to get the variables at the bottom to pass values.

Comment: `%BUILD_CONFIG%` - this is some windows way of getting variables values? What is the entrypoing of your gitlab docker image? `$BUILD_PUBLISH_CONFIG_TRUE` - did you try it wit imageh `${ ... }` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you place variables inside job, that mean that you want to create new variable (and thats not correct way to do it). You want to output content of variable setup on top? Can u maybe add that to echo? or something like that?  I didn't get it what you are trying to achieve.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#gitlab-ciyml-defined-variables